How does the contract handle tax deductions for simple buy and sell transactions when the token is listed on any decentralized exchange (DEX)?
Could anyone provide an example solidity smart contract code for how to implement tax deduction using a router in a smart contract when list on DEX ? I've noticed that when adding custom tax deduction functionality within the contract, it works correctly. However, when the token is listed on a DEX like PancakeSwap, the router does not apply the tax.

Gonna totally depend on the implementation. Sometimes can get around by withdrawing to weth instead of eth or other subtle things. Usually the mechanics are written without an understanding of how all contracts will work together. You would have to show the code to say why. For giving examples, maybe include which tokens tax mechanic you are trying to mimic as there are many, consider maybe include the token that tax will be taken in and at what point, are you front running the sell tx and swapping for weth ahead of the user (giving a worse price), or just skimming etc.

@Maka i got it , lets say in my mind the simple 5 % buy and sell tax deduction on DEX.

Here is a code example :
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract TaxedToken is ERC20, Ownable {
    uint256 public taxPercentage = 2; // Taxe de 2%
    address public taxWallet; // Wallet pour collecter les taxes

    constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol, address _taxWallet) ERC20(name, symbol) {
        taxWallet = _taxWallet;
    }

    function setTaxPercentage(uint256 _taxPercentage) external onlyOwner {
        taxPercentage = _taxPercentage;
    }

    function setTaxWallet(address _taxWallet) external onlyOwner {
        taxWallet = _taxWallet;
    }

    function _transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal override {
        uint256 taxAmount = amount * taxPercentage / 100;
        uint256 amountAfterTax = amount - taxAmount;

        super._transfer(sender, taxWallet, taxAmount); // Transfert de la taxe au wallet de collecte
        super._transfer(sender, recipient, amountAfterTax); // Transfert du montant après taxe au destinataire
    }
}

It is important to note that in order to make this contract work correctly on a decentralized exchange, we would need to add a whitelist, in order to not tax certain transfers involving the liquidity pair.
